# KivyMD BottomSheet lags every time it opens

Tags: python, kivy, lag, kivymd, bottom-sheet

When I run app and click button that do:

```
    def show_example_custom_bottom_sheet(self):
        self.custom_sheet = MDCustomBottomSheet(screen=Factory.ContentCustomSheet(),
                                                radius_from="top",
                                                radius=25,
                                                animation=True
                                                )
        self.custom_sheet.open()
```

BottomSheet opens after about 1 second or less. The main question is: Can i do something to prevent that or I just need to wait until KivyMD 1.2 will be released and maybe it will be changed? Below is my code in a shorter form.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition, SwapTransition, SlideTransition, \
    CardTransition, WipeTransition, RiseInTransition

from kivymd.uix.bottomsheet import MDCustomBottomSheet
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRoundFlatIconButton


KV = '''    
#=================================================================================================
#Renamed & Set 
  
<NovaButton@OneLineAvatarIconListItem>:
    #radius: 20
    #_no_ripple_effect: True

<BackButton>:
    pos_hint: {"left": 1}
    font_size: "18dp"
    icon: "chevron-left"
    _no_ripple_effect: True
    line_color: 0, 0, 0, 0

<CenterLabel@MDLabel>:
    font_size: "24dp"
    halign: "center"
    size_hint: 0.5, 1

#=================================================================================================
#ScreenManger inside BottomSheet (Content of BottomSheet below that) 

<MenuScreenManager>:
    id: id_screen_manager

    
    ScreenMain:
        id: id_screen_main
        name: "screen_main"
        ScrollView:
            MDGridLayout:
                adaptive_height: True
                cols: 1

                NovaButton:
                    text: "Language"
                    on_release: id_screen_manager.screen_change("go", "language")

                    IconLeftWidgetWithoutTouch:
                        icon: "earth"
                    IconRightWidgetWithoutTouch:
                        icon: "chevron-right"

                NovaButton:
                    text: "Record"
                    on_release: id_screen_manager.screen_change("go", "record")

                    IconLeftWidgetWithoutTouch:
                        icon: "video-image"
                    IconRightWidgetWithoutTouch:
                        icon: "chevron-right"

                

    ScreenLanguage:
        id: id_screen_language
        name: "screen_language"

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            GridLayout:
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: "50dp"
                cols: 3

                #Menu on top (BackButton & CenterLabel & free space)
                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint: 0.25, 1
                    BackButton:
                        text: "Settings"
                        on_release: id_screen_manager.screen_change("back", "main")         
                CenterLabel
                    text: "Language" 
                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint: 0.25, 1


            ScrollView:
                MDGridLayout:
                    adaptive_height: True
                    cols: 1

                    TwoLineRightIconListItem:
                        text: "Polski"
                        secondary_text: "Polish"
                        secondary_font_style: "Body2"
                        radius: 20, 20, 20, 20

                    TwoLineRightIconListItem:
                        text: "English"
                        secondary_text: "English"
                        secondary_font_style: "Body2"

                        IconRightWidgetWithoutTouch:
                            icon: "check"

                    TwoLineRightIconListItem:
                        text: "Deutsch"
                        secondary_text: "German"
                        secondary_font_style: "Body2"



    ScreenRecord:
        id: id_screen_record
        name: "screen_record"

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            GridLayout:
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: "50dp"
                cols: 3

                #Menu on top (BackButton & CenterLabel & free space)
                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint: 0.25, 1
                    BackButton:
                        text: "Settings"
                        on_release: id_screen_manager.screen_change("back", "main")           
                CenterLabel:
                    text: "Record"
                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint: 0.25, 1

            ScrollView:
                MDGridLayout:
                    adaptive_height: True
                    cols: 1


                    NovaButton:
                        text: "Record"
                        on_release: id_screen_record.screen_change("back_to_menu")

                        IconLeftWidgetWithoutTouch:
                            icon: "video-outline"
                        IconRightWidgetWithoutTouch:
                            icon: "chevron-right"


#=================================================================================================
#Content of BottomSheet 

<ContentCustomSheet>:  
    orientation: "vertical"
    size_hint_y: None
    height: Window.size[1]/2
    md_bg_color: 1, 1, 1, 0

    MDAnchorLayout:
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: "50dp"
        MDIcon: 
            icon: "minus"
            font_size: "40dp"
            color: 0.8, 0.8, 0.8
            # icon_size: "40dp"
            # theme_icon_color: "Custom"
            # icon_color: 0.8, 0.8, 0.8
            size_hint: 1, 1
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": 1}
            #on_release: app.custom_sheet.dismiss()

    MenuScreenManager:


#=================================================================================================
#Screen at beginning 

MDScreen:
    MDIconButton:  #<-- MenuButton
        icon: "menu"
        size_hint: 0.1, 0.1
        icon_size: "50dp"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "bottom": 1}
        on_release: app.show_example_custom_bottom_sheet()


'''


class ContentCustomSheet(BoxLayout):
    pass


class BackButton(MDRoundFlatIconButton):
    pass


class MenuScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    def screen_change(self, direct, to):

        match direct:
            case "go":
                self.transition.direction = "left"
            case "back":
                self.transition.direction = "right"

        self.current = f"screen_{to}"


class ScreenMain(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenLanguage(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenRecord(Screen):
    pass


class Example(MDApp):
    custom_sheet = None
    sm = ScreenManager(transition=SwapTransition())
    sm.add_widget(ScreenMain(name="screen_main"))
    sm.add_widget(ScreenLanguage(name="screen_language"))
    sm.add_widget(ScreenRecord(name="screen_record"))

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def show_example_custom_bottom_sheet(self):
        self.custom_sheet = MDCustomBottomSheet(screen=Factory.ContentCustomSheet(),
                                                radius_from="top",
                                                radius=25,
                                                animation=True
                                                )
        self.custom_sheet.open()


Example().run()
```

I know that it can occur, because of creating every time self.custom_sheet (like it should I guess), but after trying to solve that I checked example code in kivymd documentation and it lags there a bit too. I tried to seperate Screens from "Content" to make the program have a bit less to load, but It did nothing. Maybe it just cannot be changed.